# How to add condition to rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame `df`:

```
COL1   COL2   COL3   Y
10     2      A      1
20     5      A      3
30     2      B      1
20     7      B      4
15     2      A      2
25     1      B      1
10     3      A      1
25     1      A      1
```

I  apply rolling to `y` as follows:

```
window = 2
y = df["Y"]
y = y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.max(x) if len(x)>0 else 0).dropna()
```

But now I need to add a restriction to `y`: the `max` should be calculated only over rows where `COL3` is equal to `A`.
If there is no `A` value in rows, then `y` should be equal to 0. For example, rows 3 and 4 (if we use the `window` of 2)

I tried:

```
y = df.rolling(window).apply(lambda row: np.max(row[row["COL3"=="A"]]["Y"]) if len(row["Y"])>0 else 0).dropna()["Y"]
```

But got the error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the y before the `rolling` and `reindex` fill the value with 0

```
y1 = y[df.COL3 == 'A']
y1 = y1.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.max(x) if len(x)>0 else 0).fillna('drop')
y = y1.reindex(y.index, fill_value = 0).loc[lambda x : x!='drop']
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why reindexing is needed?

Comment: @Fluxy cause I only select col3 equal to A, and we do the calculation only for them, so the other row is missing , we then reindex back